# Paginate results from data fetched through array

Tags: pagination

I'm bit confused about paginating the results generated from an array in WordPress. I've a couple of event Ids per user that I'm saving as a string: -

```
id | userid | eventids
1  |  22    |  33,45,554, 225
```

I fetch these results using $wpdb->get_var ($query), for which I get a string "33,45,554,225". I'm then converting this string into an array so that I can process it further.

So, `$eventsList = explode ( ",", $wpdb->get_var($query) );`

I then fetch the event titles using following loop:

```
foreach ( $eventsList as $event ) {
 echo get_the_title ($event); 
}
```

Now the problem is that I do not know how to paginate these results. I've the following standard code that generates the pagination links, but each page shows the same data.

```
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
$countOfEvents        = count( $eventsList );
$page_count      = ceil($countOfEvents / $eventsPerPage );

$employer_dashboard_pagination_args = array(

    'base'  => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url (get_pagenum_link( $big )) ),
    'format' => '/page/%#%',
    'current'   => $paged,
    'total' => $page_count,
    'prev_text' => '&#171; Previous',
    'next_text' => 'Next &#187;'
);
```

Would really appreciate if someone could help fixing this problem.

Comment: Explode returns a Key=>name array. Does your event title foreach loop works ?

Comment: Yes, it does return ( '0' => 33, '1' => 45, '2' => 554, '3' => 225 ) , which I iterate. So I can actually display a list of events, but not able to paginate them.

Answer (score 0):

Okay! I fixed it all by myself. Adding it here so that it can help others looking for a solution.

For all things 'posts' (and post types), WP_QUERY is your friend. Do go through all the arguments it accepts. I found out that the parameter 'post__in' accepts the IDs of the posts and then fetches those posts for you. You can paginate them easily.

I simply pass my $eventList array to 'post__in' parameter and it does what I was trying to do.